# Intellij postgres can't see tables even though connected

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use the database tool in intellij (pycharm) instead of the usual postgres cli `psql`.
However although the IDE can connect to postgres and see the different databases I can't seem to see any tables within in for some reason. There doesn't seem to be a helpful guide to set this up unfortunately.
Intellij:
[image: db config]

psql:
[image: db tables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection to the database needs to be specific to that database not just the general postgres database.

eg in View-> Tool windows-> Database

Then click on database setting icon and for the url have (on osx at least):

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourdatabase`

Comment: I had a similar issue with schema. The database panel offers a popup in which you can select "All databases", which seemed like a no-brainer to me so I ticked it. Ticking this prevents you being able to select any schemas, for me at least, never seen this before so no idea what else I'd done. I had to un-tick "All databases", and then selecting "All schemas" worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The real issue I had was using `localhost` instead of my local ip (`192.168.***.***`). That is even more strange because i could still use `localhost` with `psql`, but not with IntelliJ (nor with my code).

The force refresh tip (*see below*) can still be helpful

---

I had the same issue just today. Connection string was fine and was able to connect via `psql` too, but Intellij was not showing the tables for some reason.
The normal "File > Invalidate caches..." trick didnt work either.

To me what worked was doing a Force Refresh.

[image: IntelliJ Force Refresh button]

It appears to me there is some caching going on with the databases view that isnt being cleared up with the normal "File > Invalidate caches..." method